# Canvas URL is not a valid URL

Tags: facebook, canvas, settings

I am creating a new canvas app, unfortunately, the validator won't accept my canvas URL.

The only thing that I can see that could cause problems is that the canvas url has subdomains?

http://foo_bar.baz.larmaz.com/ (Not the real domain, of course)

Also, the Facebook debugger tool can successfully scrape the page without errors.

Any ideas why this might be occuring?

Comment: Can we please see some code?

Comment: There really isn't any code. I successfully created a facebook app and set the app domain to: larmaz.com (not real) When I tried to add an App on Facebook, the form rejected my canvas url http://foo_bar.baz.larmaz.com. The site is live, and runs successfully on the debug tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it without the underscore, as http://foobar.baz.larmaz.com/ and it worked for me.

Comment: I'll try to alter the DNS entry to see if the underscore is not allowed in the regex. If so, I'll up vote this answer. Is this noted anywhere on the FB site?

Comment: Perfect. I altered the DNS entries to remove underscores (_) and facebook accepted the URL.